# Google Compute API Anonymous Requests

Tags: google-compute-engine

Just noticed I have thousands of anonymous requests hitting all of the compute engine api list endpoints. I have no instances running and I'm only using Firebase and Cloud Build, Source, and Registry. Please see attached screenshot of API metrics report.

Any reason for this?

[compute engine metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00N6v.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the backend there are certain API calls needed to make sure that your project is healthy, these "Anonymous" requests represent an account used by the backend service making health checks.

Anonymous API calls (this could be just Compute Engine “list” calls) doesn't imply having enabled something from your side. A lot of different sections in the Console make calls to the Compute Engine API and there’s no easy way to figure out which section made the calls, but they are expected.

These kind of "Anonymous" Compute Engine APIs are part of the internal Monitoring tools  needed to make sure that your project is healthy and are randomly triggered. These metrics might eventually disappear and come back throughout the project life.

Comment: I'm ok with that, but it would be better if Google identified these as "Google" or something equivalent so I can identify "real" anonymous calls. Thanks!